# Classic ASP, How do I delete a cookie with the same name but different path?

Tags: cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

I still have some classic ASP pages in a web app and all cookies should have a path of "/".  Somehow I'm getting a cookie created with a different path, "/lmw" and I want to delete just that one.   I've tried setting the path first and expiring the cookie but it deletes them all... setting it last does the same thing.

```
response.cookie("LS").path = "/lmw"
response.cookie("LS").expires = dateAdd("d",-10,date())
response.cookie("LS").path = "/lmw"
```

But like I said, that deletes the cookie "LS" with a path of "/" too.  So, in classic ASP, how do I delete cookie with the "/lmw" path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.  Apparently, within one session if you kill one cookie, you kill the other.  So, I wrote a small script that expires the /LMW cookie and call it via AJAX so it's in a session all by itself.  So far, all the tests have worked so I'm feeling pretty good now.